# Sorting even number and odd number in single line

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections, java-ee-5, javacc

This is an Interview question.

Say you have an array like this

```
{54,23,545,65,23,4,1,2,5}
```

How to sort it and classify as even or odd in a single line of code?

The answer's order of complexity should be O(1), without using any `for` loop. The result should be:

```
{2,4,54,1,5,23,23,65,545}
```

Comment: What a pity, not tagged with Scala: `array.sortBy(n => (n % 2 != 0, n))` does the job

Comment: @Beryllium But the complexity should be O(1) if you use modulus then we have to use for loop

Comment: Both solutions use quicksort in the end, so the overall complexity is never O(1) generally speaking. The expression in the Scala solution is probably called as often as compare in the Java solution, so I do not see a difference here. The difference is to use tuples, and a sort method which compares based on tuples.

Comment: Is it possible for you to code  exact lines, please

Comment: There are no tuples in Java, no rich collections, no closures. So AFAIK any Java answer looks like the one you have got. Looking at the question, I would even say that there is no real answer to do this in a single *logical* line at all (which means: without anonymous classes or closures).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If instantiating and using an anonymous implementation of `Comparator` can be considered a single line:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>(){public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {return o1%2 == o2%2 ? o1.compareTo(o2) : (o1%2 == 0 ? -1 : 1); }});
```

[**Ideone** demo](http://ideone.com/ToJHfI).

Comment: This what i expected , awesome searched in google. Had not got answer for this hope so in future it will be usefull for many during interview

Comment: @Xavi , can we do this with Comparable also , if so , can u add to answer ?

Comment: In order to use `Comparable` you'd have to define a custom class wrapping an `int`, have it implement `Comparable` and then you could call `Arrays.sort(arr)` without specifying a custom comparator. The comparison logic would be defined in the `Comparable#compareTo` method of the custom wrapper class.